# packets coming out of a 10.10 network with 192.168 source addresses

Tags: spoofing, nat

Since there are only a few different source addresses and they are all within valid subnets for the types of routers on our network (mostly netgear & mikrotik), I assume this means that this traffic is coming from local networks and not the routers themselves (seems like if it was from hacked routers, we would see a larger variety of source addresses).

If this is the case, then how are packets with 192.168 source addresses leaving routers with 10.10 public IP addresses? Is there a way to set up the firewalls of the individual mikrotik routers to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Mikrotiks are extremely complex to configure and will work incorrectly if not configured properly.  192.168 traffic can be from a rouge router inside your network or something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to block or allow the relevant traffic on MikroTik RouterOS device.

I am pretty sure it's not hacked routers, maybe they are not configured properly.
You can use an Address link like LAN_Networks and allow only them.
The example at their wiki site is pretty simple:
https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Firewall/Address_list